# Dreamweaver Template '@@'

Tags: dreamweaver, dreamweaver-templates

I've been researching the use of templates and repeating sections with Dreamweaver and I was reading the Adobe page on repeating sections (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7ab0a.html).

At the bottom of the page there is an example of using a repeating section with a table and making the row background colours alternate using

```
<tr bgcolor="@@( _index & 1 ? '#FFFFFF' : '#CCCCCC' )@@">
```

Curious about this '@@' tag, I started Googling 'dreamweaver double at' and similar things but failed to find anything. It appears to be some sort of script, however I can't find any further information about it. If anyone could point me in the correct direction that would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are template expression.  Look here [Template expressions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7acca.html#WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7ac6a)